# How can I add text to all posts/pages/categories/homepage etc

Tags: functions, content

This should be an easy thing but I just can't get it right.

I need to add a piece of HTML to every page on my site however the weird theme I'm using doesn't have a header or footer file that every page uses and I don't want to duplicate code.

So what I did was add the following to my functions.php file

```
add_filter ('the_content', 'AddTrackingScript');

function AddTrackingScript($content) {
    $Tracker .= '<script type="text/javascript">....</script>';
    $content = $Disclaimer .= $content;
    return content;
}
```

This works on all articles and pages however the text isn't being added to my home page or to the category pages. Is there a different filter I need to use other than the_content?

There is a lot more logic in my real function as certain posts in certain categories don't get the added text but I've simplified it here, just in case someone spots a type ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to some outside help the answer was simplistic, I just need to hook into this

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'AddTrackingScript' );
```

and then simply echo it out and it then gets spat out at the end of the page.

```
function AddTrackingScript() {
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">....</script>';
}
```